# Is it really a best practice to use jstl out tag?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

I remember working on a project with a group of developers and they always wanted static
 html text to be inside of an out tag (`<c:out value="words" />`). I don't remember why
 this was the case.

Is this really a best practice when building jsp pages?  What are the 
advantages/disadvantages of such an approach?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a terrible idea for static text.  You then have no barrier as to what is static and what is dynamically generated.

Besides which, on Servlet Spec 2.3+ you can have dynamic text mixed with static text as:

This is static, not `${dynamic}` text.

The only reasons to use `c:out` tags, in my experience:

1. You're using an older servlet spec, and need them to output DYNAMIC text in some fashion
2. You want to escape `HTML` output to avoid using `<>`, etc, replacing ampersands with their control codes, etc.

Otherwise, having them use static text confuses the programmer or maintainer...now where did I put that **EL**?  It was in a `c:out` tag...but so was fifty other lines of static text!

Comment: I think that escaping is the primary reason today to use c:out.

Comment: As long as you're not using an older servlet spec (which some people are still forced to do, unfortunately, luckily I am not one of these poor souls), I agree with you - the escaping XML is lovely.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just printing out plain text it's better to do it in HTML.  The advantage of the `c:out` tag is that you can evaluate expressions inside the tag.

```
<c:out value="Hello ${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}"/>
```

Comment: That advantage disappears in Servlet Spec 2.3+, when the container is able to provide EL support directly.  As such, c:out should not be used just to output EL in a Servlet Spec 2.3+ container, when Hello ${user.firstName} ${user.lastName} is more readable without the c:out around it.

Comment: Just be aware that EL does not escape special HTML characters. If the EL is outputting data supplied by a user theis leaves the application open to nasty security vulnerabilities such as cross-site scripting.